# Zapier - Javascript wrong custom function behaviour

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, zapier

I defined a function numberFormat in my Zapier app

I was expecting a result like `50` but actually I get `5000`. Any suggestions about how to solve this?

```js
function numberFormat(number) {
  var newString = number.toString().replace(/,/g, '.'); // togli tutte le virgole e sostituiscile con punti
  var lastDotIndex = newString.lastIndexOf('.'); // l'ultimo che trovi è separatore dei decimali
  var decimal = newString.slice(lastDotIndex); // parte decimale
  var integerSlice = newString.slice(0, lastDotIndex); // parte intera
  var integer = integerSlice.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // della parte intera mi servono solo i numeri
  var strResult = integer + decimal; // concatena intero e decimale

  return Number(strResult);
}

// In this same environment I sent a test value like this:

console.log(numberFormat("50,00"));
```

Comment: The code above produces 50 in Chrome. I do not see any ES6 code either

Comment: @mplungjan indeed. I cannot reproduce this. I tried it in IE11 which is the closest I have to an ES5 environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dot or just take the replacements and get a number from it.

```js
function numberFormat(number) {
    return +number
        .toString()
        .replace(/,/g, '.')
        .replace(/\.(?=.*\.)/g, '')
        .replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''); // allow dot
}

console.log(numberFormat("50,00"));
console.log(numberFormat("1,000,00"))
```

Comment: If I send `console.log(numberFormat("1,000,00"))` it returns `1.000.00`, but what I would get is `1000`.

Comment: it still returns `1000` instead of `10`, that's strange, because when I run your snippet in Jsfiddle it works.